# How to declare function in MasterPage.Master instead of code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my MasterPage.Master I have this code:

```
<% if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["FullVersion"])) { %>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Gå til mobilversjon"     OnClick="GoToMobileVersion" runat="server" />
<% } %>
```

Instead of declaring this function in MasterPage.master.cs like this:

```
protected void GoToMobileVersion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageBase page = (PageBase)Page;
    page.Session["FullVersion"] = false;
    Response.Redirect(Server.UrlPathEncode(page.CurrentPage.LinkURL));
}
```

I would like to do the declare the function in  MasterPage.Master.
What syntax would I use to do this?

Here is what I want to do:

```
    <% 
protected void GoToMobileVersion ()
{
Session["FullVersion"] = false;
Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define functions with script runat="server" block,

```
<script runat="server">
 protected void GoToMobileVersion ()
 {
  Session["FullVersion"] = false;
  Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
 }
</script>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh(v=vs.100).aspx